# How to properly setup Fish and version the configuration?

Tags: shell, fish

I'm switching to fish from zsh and I'm struggling to find the correct way to it setup for my taste. Also adding that I want to add it to my `dotfiles` repository. Should I version the whole `~/.config/fish` folder?

Where should I put my environment variables? Should I just add them to the `fish_variables` config file? I was thinking on sourcing a file `~/variables.fish` for the ones I don't want to version. Is this a good idea?

I use `exa` and `ripgrep` and I like to override `grep` and `ls` with them. Can I just set aliases for them overriding like I would with zsh/bash?

I want to use it inside neovim as well and I'm using the vi keybindings. Will this conflict with neovim? If so is there a way to make the vi keybindings active only outside of neovim?

It seems most of the stuff I use is provided by vanilla fish without plugins (which I'm quite happy about). Is there any tips or must have plugins I should install?

Comment: You're seeing some close votes because stackoverflow isn't the right place for user configuration questions. This really belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). However the active fish community is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my ~/.config/fish in git, works well.
I share my config over several machines, and to have host-specific settings and functions, I do this:

```
# machine-specific
set host_config ~/.config/fish/config.(hostname).fish
test -r $host_config; and source $host_config
set -e host_config

set host_funcdir ~/.config/fish/functions_(hostname)
test -d $host_funcdir; and set fish_function_path $host_funcdir $fish_function_path
set -e host_funcdir
```

I'm not a fan of universal variables.
Contrary to the [fish philosophy](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/design.html#configurability-is-the-root-of-all-evil), I like configuration.
I store *global* variables in the config.fish file.

fish aliases create functions behind the scenes, so I do that upfront.
This is my `~/.config/fish/functions/ls.fish`

```
function ls --wraps=exa
  exa --classify $argv
end
```

Using --wraps is helpful to tab-complete exa options while you're typing a `ls` command.

I don't know about neovim/fish integration.

I have oh-my-fish installed, but only for [fish-logo](https://github.com/laughedelic/fish_logo)